# Пропадает текст перед <br>

Tags: html

Вот пример собственно.

```css
@media (max-width:560px){.col-xs-6.col-xss-12{width:100%}}select.disable-native-behavior{appearance:none;-moz-appearance:none;-webkit-appearance:none}select.disable-native-behavior::-ms-expand{display:none}.uppercase{text-transform:uppercase}.no-select{-webkit-user-select:none;-moz-user-select:none;-ms-user-select:none;user-select:none}.popup-image{cursor:zoom-out;position:fixed;height:100%;width:100%;top:0;left:0;display:none;text-align:center}.popup-image .popup_bg{position:absolute;z-index:1;background:black;opacity:.6;filter:alpha(opacity=60);height:100%;width:100%}.popup-image .popup_img{position:relative;margin:0 auto;z-index:2;max-height:94%;max-width:94%;margin:1% 0 0 0}.popup-image .close-pop-up{position:absolute;font-size:50px;color:white;z-index:3;top:-12px}*{margin:0;padding:0;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}img{border:0;outline:none}a{border:0}.inline_block{display:-moz-inline-stack;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;zoom:1;*display:inline}.pos_relative{position:relative}div.table{display:table}div.inline_table{display:inline-table}div.table div.trow,div.inline_table div.trow{display:table-row}div.table div.trow div.tcell,div.inline_table div.trow div.tcell{display:table-cell;vertical-align:top}div.cookie_notice{margin-top:10px !important;padding:20px !important;border:1px solid #cccccc;border-radius:15px;color:#777777 !important;background-color:#eff7f7}div.cookie_notice a{color:#00a2e0;text-decoration:none;border-bottom:1px dotted #00a2e0}div.cookie_notice a:hover{border-bottom:0;text-decoration:underline}div.cookie_notice img.close_frame{position:absolute;top:3px;right:3px;opacity:.6;cursor:pointer}div.cookie_notice img.close_frame:hover{opacity:.8}div.tracking_pixels{position:absolute;top:-200px;left:-200px;z-index:-100}.ui-widget-overlay{position:fixed;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;background:black;opacity:.6;filter:alpha(opacity=60)}.ui-front{z-index:100}.text-placeholder{color:#AAA !important}.landing-debug-info{color:#aaa}iframe[name="google_conversion_frame"]{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:1px;height:1px}.old-ie .col-xs-1,.old-ie .col-xs-2,.old-ie .col-xs-3,.old-ie .col-xs-4,.old-ie .col-xs-5,.old-ie .col-xs-6,.old-ie .col-xs-7,.old-ie .col-xs-8,.old-ie .col-xs-9,.old-ie .col-xs-10,.old-ie .col-xs-11,.old-ie .col-xs-12,.old-ie .col-sm-1,.old-ie .col-sm-2,.old-ie .col-sm-3,.old-ie .col-sm-4,.old-ie .col-sm-5,.old-ie .col-sm-6,.old-ie .col-sm-7,.old-ie .col-sm-8,.old-ie .col-sm-9,.old-ie .col-sm-10,.old-ie .col-sm-11,.old-ie .col-sm-12,.old-ie .col-md-1,.old-ie .col-md-2,.old-ie .col-md-3,.old-ie .col-md-4,.old-ie .col-md-5,.old-ie .col-md-6,.old-ie .col-md-7,.old-ie .col-md-8,.old-ie .col-md-9,.old-ie .col-md-10,.old-ie .col-md-11,.old-ie .col-md-12,.old-ie .col-lg-1,.old-ie .col-lg-2,.old-ie .col-lg-3,.old-ie .col-lg-4,.old-ie .col-lg-5,.old-ie .col-lg-6,.old-ie .col-lg-7,.old-ie .col-lg-8,.old-ie .col-lg-9,.old-ie .col-lg-10,.old-ie .col-lg-11,.old-ie .col-lg-12{float:none;width:auto;display:inline-block}.old-ie .container{width:1200px !important}.old-ie .row>*{vertical-align:top}html{font-size:1em}body{background:#eeeeee;font-family:'Open Sans',sans-serif,Tahoma,Verdana,Georgia;font-size:80%;color:black;text-align:left}ul,ol{list-style:none}p{margin-bottom:0}a{text-decoration:underline}h2{text-align:center;font-size:240%;font-weight:bold;padding-bottom:30px}@media (max-width:767px){h2{padding:0;font-size:150% !important}}@media (min-width:768px){.container{width:750px}}@media (min-width:992px){.container{width:900px}}.congretulation,.courses-design,.courses-english,.courses-german,.courses-italian,.courses-manicure,.courses-other,.courses-poland,.courses-psyhology,.courses-sew,.market-sbs,.market-full,.certificate-1,.logo-white,.IgorNevzorov,.ElenaMatvienko,.AlinaPetrakova,.certificate-2,.scroll-top-arrow,.prize,.list-item-hand-black,.home,.phone,.white-button-arrow,.select-button,.black-button-arrow,.condition-mark{display:inline-block;background:url('/landingpageimg/044/full-sprite-20161219.png') no-repeat;overflow:hidden;text-indent:-9999px;text-align:left}.congretulation{background-position:-2px 0;width:557px;height:89px}.courses-design{background-position:-2px -91px;width:207px;height:124px}.courses-english{background-position:-211px -91px;width:207px;height:124px}.courses-german{background-position:-2px -217px;width:207px;height:124px}.courses-italian{background-position:-211px -217px;width:207px;height:124px}.courses-manicure{background-position:-2px -343px;width:207px;height:124px}.courses-other{background-position:-211px -343px;width:207px;height:124px}.courses-poland{background-position:-2px -469px;width:207px;height:124px}.courses-psyhology{background-position:-211px -469px;width:207px;height:124px}.courses-sew{background-position:-2px -595px;width:207px;height:124px}.market-sbs{background-position:-211px -595px;width:200px;height:160px}.market-full{background-position:-2px -721px;width:200px;height:160px}.certificate-1{background-position:-204px -757px;width:169px;height:119px}.logo-white{background-position:-420px -91px;width:130px;height:55px}.IgorNevzorov{background-position:-420px -148px;width:105px;height:105px}.ElenaMatvienko{background-position:-420px -255px;width:101px;height:101px}.AlinaPetrakova{background-position:-420px -358px;width:99px;height:99px}.certificate-2{background-position:-420px -459px;width:98px;height:138px}.scroll-top-arrow{background-position:-413px -599px;width:70px;height:70px}.prize{background-position:-485px -599px;width:65px;height:97px}.list-item-hand-black{background-position:-413px -671px;width:41px;height:41px}.home{background-position:-527px -148px;width:27px;height:37px}.phone{background-position:-527px -187px;width:27px;height:27px}.white-button-arrow{background-position:-527px -216px;width:23px;height:32px}.select-button{background-position:-527px -250px;width:21px;height:16px}.black-button-arrow{background-position:-523px -268px;width:20px;height:34px}.condition-mark{background-position:-523px -304px;width:17px;height:17px}.header{background:#ef7200;padding-top:20px;padding-bottom:20px;font-weight:bold;color:white;z-index:1}@media (max-width:767px){.header{padding-top:12px;padding-bottom:12px}}.header .logo{display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;margin-top:6px;margin-right:15px}.header .logo:before{content:'';display:block;display:inline-block;background:url('/landingpageimg/044/full-sprite-20161219.png') no-repeat;overflow:hidden;text-indent:-9999px;text-align:left;background-position:-420px -91px;width:130px;height:55px}@media (max-width:365px){.header .logo{margin-right:0}.header .logo:before{-webkit-transform:scale(.8);-moz-transform:scale(.8);-o-transform:scale(.8);-ms-transform:scale(.8);transform:scale(.8);-webkit-transform-origin:center left 0;-moz-transform-origin:center left 0;-o-transform-origin:center left 0;-ms-transform-origin:center left 0;transform-origin:center left 0}}.header .c86,.header .experience-23,.header .freecall,.header .homepage{position:relative;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;margin-right:15px;padding-left:65px}.header .c86 .item,.header .experience-23 .item,.header .freecall .item,.header .homepage .item{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;width:55px;height:55px;padding-top:8px;text-align:center;border-radius:100%;background-color:#fd954f;font-size:200%}.header .c86 .item:before,.header .experience-23 .item:before,.header .freecall .item:before,.header .homepage .item:before{display:inline-block;vertical-align:top}.header .c86{padding-top:20px;font-size:110%}.header .c86 .item:before{content:'86'}@media (max-width:711px){.header .c86{display:none}}.header .experience-23{padding-top:20px;font-size:110%}.header .experience-23 .item:before{content:'24'}@media (max-width:991px){.header .experience-23{display:none}}.header .freecall{display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;float:right;padding-top:7px;color:white}.header .freecall:hover{color:#337ab7}.header .freecall .item:before{content:'';display:inline-block;background:url('/landingpageimg/044/full-sprite-20161219.png') no-repeat;overflow:hidden;text-indent:-9999px;text-align:left;background-position:-527px -187px;width:27px;height:27px;margin-top:7px}.header .freecall .number{font-weight:bold;font-size:120%}@media (max-width:580px){.header .freecall{display:none}}.header .homepage{display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;float:right;padding-top:20px;color:white}.header .homepage:hover{color:#337ab7}.header .homepage .item:before{content:'';display:inline-block;background:url('/landingpageimg/044/full-sprite-20161219.png') no-repeat;overflow:hidden;text-indent:-9999px;text-align:left;background-position:-527px -148px;width:27px;height:37px}@media (max-width:991px){.header .homepage{padding-top:16px}}@media (max-width:365px){.header .homepage{margin-right:0;padding-left:50px}.header .homepage .item{-webkit-transform:scale(.8);-moz-transform:scale(.8);-o-transform:scale(.8);-ms-transform:scale(.8);transform:scale(.8);-webkit-transform-origin:center left 0;-moz-transform-origin:center left 0;-o-transform-origin:center left 0;-ms-transform-origin:center left 0;transform-origin:center left 0}}.promo{background:url('/landingpageimg/044/promo-bg-20161219.png') #fee249;height:auto}@media (min-width:768px){.promo{overflow:hidden}}@media (min-width:992px){.promo{height:720px}}.promo .container{position:relative;height:100%}@media (max-width:767px){.promo .container{padding-left:0;padding-right:0}}.promo .container .row{position:relative}@media (max-width:767px){.promo .container .row{margin-left:0;margin-right:0}}@media (max-width:767px){.promo .container [class^="col-"]{padding-left:0;padding-right:0}}.promo .info{margin-top:40px;position:relative}@media (max-width:558px){.promo .info{overflow:hidden}.promo .info .congretulation{margin-left:calc((100% - 320px) / 2);-webkit-transform:scale(.57);-moz-transform:scale(.57);-o-transform:scale(.57);-ms-transform:scale(.57);transform:scale(.57);-webkit-transform-origin:center left 0;-moz-transform-origin:center left 0;-o-transform-origin:center left 0;-ms-transform-origin:center left 0;transform-origin:center left 0}}@media (min-width:768px){.promo .info{min-height:480px}}.promo .info:after{position:absolute;content:'';background:url('/landingpageimg/044/girl-20161219.png');bottom:-40px;left:0;width:1000px;height:520px}@media (max-width:767px){.promo .info{margin-top:0;min-height:none}.promo .info:after{content:none}}.promo .info .table{position:relative;z-index:2;padding:0 40px;font-size:120%;margin-bottom:0}.promo .info .table span{vertical-align:middle;display:table-cell}.promo .info .table .market-propose{padding-top:40px;font-size:160%}@media (max-width:460px){.promo .info .table{padding:0}.promo .info .table.bonus{display:none}.promo .info .table span{display:block;margin:0 auto}.promo .info .table span.market-propose{padding:0}.promo .info .table .market-full{overflow:hidden}}.promo .info .table.bonus{top:-20px;z-index:1;background:#fff9bc;border-radius:15px;padding:20px 40px;font-weight:bold}.promo .info .table.bonus .market-propose{padding-top:0}.promo .info .table.bonus .market-sbs,.promo .info .table.bonus .market-full{background:none;height:100px;text-align:center}.promo .info .table.bonus .market-full{position:relative;padding-right:50px;overflow:visible}.promo .info .table.bonus .market-full:after{content:'';display:inline-block;background:url('/landingpageimg/044/full-sprite-20161219.png') no-repeat;overflow:hidden;text-indent:-9999px;text-align:left;background-position:-485px -599px;width:65px;height:97px;position:absolute;left:150px;top:0}@media (max-width:767px){.promo .info .table{padding:0}}.promo .girl-mobile{margin:0 auto -29px 20px;z-index:1;position:relative}@media (max-width:767px){.promo .girl-mobile{margin:0 auto -29px}}@media (max-width:502px){.promo .girl-mobile{width:320px;margin-bottom:-19px}}.promo-overflow{position:relative;background:#fe1e1e}@media (min-width:992px){.promo-overflow{position:absolute;background:none;margin:-200px auto 0;width:100%}}.promo-overflow .student-form{padding:30px 20px 15px;background:#fe1e1e;border-radius:10px;width:100%}@media (max-width:767px){.promo-overflow .student-form{margin:0;position:relative;bottom:auto;border-radius:0;border:0;padding:30px 0 15px}}.promo-overflow .student-form .form-caption{color:white;font-size:180%;padding-bottom:15px;text-align:center;font-weight:bold}@media (max-width:991px){.promo-overflow .student-form .form-caption{font-size:140%}}@media (max-width:767px){.promo-overflow .student-form .form-caption{text-align:center}}.promo-overflow .student-form form .styled-select select{appearance:none;-moz-appearance:none;-webkit-appearance:none;padding-right:30px}.promo-overflow .student-form form .styled-select:after{content:'';position:absolute;right:20px;top:9px;pointer-events:none;display:inline-block;background:url('/landingpageimg/044/full-sprite-20161219.png') no-repeat;overflow:hidden;text-indent:-9999px;text-align:left;background-position:-527px -250px;width:21px;height:16px}.promo-overflow .student-form form .form-control{margin-bottom:20px;border:1px solid #aaa;border-radius:5px;-webkit-box-shadow:inset 2px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.35);-moz-box-shadow:inset 2px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.35);box-shadow:inset 2px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.35)}.promo-overflow .student-form form #education-type-sbs input,.promo-overflow .student-form form #education-type-full input{position:absolute}.promo-overflow .student-form form #education-type-sbs label,.promo-overflow .student-form form #education-type-full label{margin-left:20px}.promo-overflow .student-form form .conditions-text{padding-left:40px;margin-bottom:15px;font-size:85%}.promo-overflow .student-form form .conditions-text:before{content:'';position:absolute;left:15px;display:inline-block;background:url('/landingpageimg/044/full-sprite-20161219.png') no-repeat;overflow:hidden;text-indent:-9999px;text-align:left;background-position:-523px -304px;width:17px;height:17px}.promo-overflow .student-form form .submitbtn{text-align:center;margin-bottom:20px}.promo-overflow .student-form form .submitbtn button{width:100%;position:relative;padding:10px;border:none;background-color:#ffff00;color:black;border-radius:5px;font-size:220%;font-weight:bold;line-height:1.2}.promo-overflow .student-form form .submitbtn button:hover{background-color:#e0e000}.promo-overflow .student-form form .submitbtn button:after,.promo-overflow .student-form form .submitbtn button:before{content:'';position:absolute;top:calc(50% - 17px);display:inline-block;background:url('/landingpageimg/044/full-sprite-20161219.png') no-repeat;overflow:hidden;text-indent:-9999px;text-align:left;background-position:-523px -268px;width:20px;height:34px}.promo-overflow .student-form form .submitbtn button:after{right:5px}.promo-overflow .student-form form .submitbtn button:before{right:15px}@media (max-width:450px){.promo-overflow .student-form form .submitbtn button{font-size:130% !important}.promo-overflow .student-form form .submitbtn button:after{top:3px}}@media (min-width:768px){.promo-overflow .student-form form .submitbtn button{padding-right:50px}.promo-overflow .student-form form .submitbtn button:after{right:25px}.promo-overflow .student-form form .submitbtn button:before{right:35px}}.promo-overflow .promo-duration{font-size:85%;text-align:right;color:black}@media (max-width:767px){.promo-overflow .promo-duration{padding:10px;text-align:left}}.courses{background:white;padding:40px 0;color:black}@media (min-width:992px){.courses{padding:120px 0 40px}.courses .left-m{margin-left:6.25%}}@media (max-width:767px){.courses{padding:10px 0}}.courses .courses-caption{text-align:center;font-size:240%;font-weight:bold}.courses .courses-list a{margin:15px;text-decoration:none;color:black;text-align:center}.courses .courses-list a .courses-block{background:#fff3d4;color:black;border-radius:10px;border:#fff3d4 solid 2px;padding:5px 0}.courses .courses-list a .courses-block:hover{border:#ef7200 solid 2px}.courses .courses-list a .courses-block div.icon{margin:0 auto;overflow:hidden}.courses .courses-list a .courses-block .content{margin-top:5px}@media (min-width:320px){.courses .courses-list a .courses-block .content{min-height:45px}}@media (min-width:540px){.courses .courses-list a .courses-block .content{min-height:22px}}@media (min-width:768px){.courses .courses-list a .courses-block .content{min-height:128px}}@media (min-width:992px){.courses .courses-list a .courses-block .content{min-height:110px}}.courses .courses-list a .courses-block .content .caption{text-transform:uppercase;font-size:140%;hyphens:auto}@media (max-width:767px){.courses .courses-list a .courses-block .content .caption{font-size:120%}}.courses .courses-list a .courses-block .content .description{font-size:105%;padding:0 5px}.courses .courses-list a .courses-block .button{display:inline-block;position:relative;text-decoration:none;font-weight:bold;font-size:160%;margin:30px auto;padding:10px 75px 10px 50px;color:white;background-color:#f52020;border:2px solid white;border-radius:15px;cursor:pointer;-webkit-box-shadow:0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);-moz-box-shadow:0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);box-shadow:0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);width:80%;font-size:120%;margin:10px 10px 15px;padding:10px 0 !important}.courses .courses-list a .courses-block .button:before,.courses .courses-list a .courses-block .button:after{content:'';position:absolute;top:calc(50% - 16px);display:inline-block;background:url('/landingpageimg/044/full-sprite-20161219.png') no-repeat;overflow:hidden;text-indent:-9999px;text-align:left;background-position:-527px -216px;width:23px;height:32px}.courses .courses-list a .courses-block .button:before{right:50px}.courses .courses-list a .courses-block .button:after{right:40px}.courses .courses-list a .courses-block .button:hover{background-color:#e20a0a}@media (max-width:767px){.courses .courses-list a .courses-block .button{margin:10px auto}}.courses .courses-list a .courses-block .button:before,.courses .courses-list a .courses-block .button:after{content:none}@media (max-width:767px){.courses .courses-list a .courses-block .button{padding:5px !important}}.courses .courses-list a .courses-block .icon{height:155px !important}.courses .courses-list a .courses-block .icon:before{content:'';-webkit-transform-origin:center top 0;-moz-transform-origin:center top 0;-o-transform-origin:center top 0;-ms-transform-origin:center top 0;transform-origin:center top 0;-webkit-transform:scale(1.25);-moz-transform:scale(1.25);-o-transform:scale(1.25);-ms-transform:scale(1.25);transform:scale(1.25)}@media (max-width:991px){.courses .courses-list a .courses-block .icon{height:124px !important}.courses .courses-list a .courses-block .icon:before{-webkit-transform:scale(1);-moz-transform:scale(1);-o-transform:scale(1);-ms-transform:scale(1);transform:scale(1)}}@media (max-width:529px){.courses .courses-list a .courses-block .icon{height:62px !important;max-width:103.5px;margin:10px auto}.courses .courses-list a .courses-block .icon:before{-webkit-transform:scale(.5);-moz-transform:scale(.5);-o-transform:scale(.5);-ms-transform:scale(.5);transform:scale(.5);-webkit-transform-origin:left top 0;-moz-transform-origin:left top 0;-o-transform-origin:left top 0;-ms-transform-origin:left top 0;transform-origin:left top 0}}.courses .courses-list a .courses-block .icon.icon-english:before{display:inline-block;background:url('/landingpageimg/044/full-sprite-20161219.png') no-repeat;overflow:hidden;text-indent:-9999px;text-align:left;background-position:-211px -91px;width:207px;height:124px}.courses .courses-list a .courses-block .icon.icon-poland:before{display:inline-block;background:url('/landingpageimg/044/full-sprite-20161219.png') no-repeat;overflow:hidden;text-indent:-9999px;text-align:left;background-position:-2px -469px;width:207px;height:124px}.courses .courses-list a .courses-block .icon.icon-german:before{display:inline-block;background:url('/landingpageimg/044/full-sprite-20161219.png') no-repeat;overflow:hidden;text-indent:-9999px;text-align:left;background-position:-2px -217px;width:207px;height:124px}.courses .courses-list a .courses-block .icon.icon-italian:before{display:inline-block;background:url('/landingpageimg/044/full-sprite-20161219.png') no-repeat;overflow:hidden;text-indent:-9999px;text-align:left;background-position:-211px -217px;width:207px;height:124px}.courses .courses-list a .courses-block .icon.icon-manicure:before{display:inline-block;background:url('/landingpageimg/044/full-sprite-20161219.png') no-repeat;overflow:hidden;text-indent:-9999px;text-align:left;background-position:-2px -343px;width:207px;height:124px}.courses .courses-list a .courses-block .icon.icon-sew:before{display:inline-block;background:url('/landingpageimg/044/full-sprite-20161219.png') no-repeat;overflow:hidden;text-indent:-9999px;text-align:left;background-position:-2px -595px;width:207px;height:124px}.courses .courses-list a .courses-block .icon.icon-psyhology:before{display:inline-block;background:url('/landingpageimg/044/full-sprite-20161219.png') no-repeat;overflow:hidden;text-indent:-9999px;text-align:left;background-position:-211px -469px;width:207px;height:124px}.courses .courses-list a .courses-block .icon.icon-design:before{display:inline-block;background:url('/landingpageimg/044/full-sprite-20161219.png') no-repeat;overflow:hidden;text-indent:-9999px;text-align:left;background-position:-2px -91px;width:207px;height:124px}.courses .courses-list a .courses-block .icon.icon-other:before{display:inline-block;background:url('/landingpageimg/044/full-sprite-20161219.png') no-repeat;overflow:hidden;text-indent:-9999px;text-align:left;background-position:-211px -343px;width:207px;height:124px}.reasons{background:#fee249;color:black}.reasons .row{position:relative}.reasons .reasons-caption{padding:30px 0}.reasons .reasons-list li{position:relative;padding-left:70px;margin-bottom:25px}@media (max-width:767px){.reasons .reasons-list li:before{content:'';position:absolute;top:0;left:15px;display:inline-block;background:url('/landingpageimg/044/full-sprite-20161219.png') no-repeat;overflow:hidden;text-indent:-9999px;text-align:left;background-position:-413px -671px;width:41px;height:41px}}.reasons .reasons-list li .caption{margin-bottom:10px;font-size:140%;text-transform:uppercase}.reasons .reasons-list li .description{font-weight:bold}@media (min-width:768px){.reasons .overflow{position:absolute;height:0}.reasons .overflow button{position:relative;top:-25px;margin:0 auto}}.feedbacks{padding:40px 0 0;background:white;color:black}@media (max-width:767px){.feedbacks{padding-top:20px;padding-bottom:10px}}.feedbacks .feedback{position:relative}@media (max-width:767px){.feedbacks .feedback{margin-bottom:30px}}.feedbacks .feedback .photo{position:absolute;top:0;left:calc(50% - 50px)}.feedbacks .feedback .photo.AlinaPetrakova{display:inline-block;background:url('/landingpageimg/044/full-sprite-20161219.png') no-repeat;overflow:hidden;text-indent:-9999px;text-align:left;background-position:-420px -358px;width:99px;height:99px}.feedbacks .feedback .photo.ElenaMatvienko{display:inline-block;background:url('/landingpageimg/044/full-sprite-20161219.png') no-repeat;overflow:hidden;text-indent:-9999px;text-align:left;background-position:-420px -255px;width:101px;height:101px}.feedbacks .feedback .photo.IgorNevzorov{display:inline-block;background:url('/landingpageimg/044/full-sprite-20161219.png') no-repeat;overflow:hidden;text-indent:-9999px;text-align:left;background-position:-420px -148px;width:105px;height:105px}.feedbacks .text{background:#fff3d4;color:black;margin-top:60px;padding:25px 15px;padding-top:60px;border-radius:10px;font-size:110%}.feedbacks .text .more{display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;margin-top:10px}.feedbacks .text .sign{display:block;margin-top:10px}.certificates{background:#fee249;color:black;padding:25px 0;text-align:center}.certificates .text{font-size:190%;padding:35px 0;font-weight:bold}.certificates .cert{cursor:zoom-in}.certificates .certificate-1:before,.certificates .certificate-2:before{content:'';display:block}.certificates .certificate-1:before{content:'';display:block}.certificates .certificate-2:before{content:'';display:block}.popup{display:none;padding-bottom:30px;background:#ef7200}.popup .row{margin:0}.popup .header .promo-text{font-weight:bold;font-size:220%;padding-right:150px;text-align:center}@media (max-width:767px){.popup .header .promo-text{display:none}}@media (min-width:900px){.popup .columns{-webkit-column-count:2;-moz-column-count:2;column-count:2;-webkit-column-width:45%;-moz-column-width:45%;column-width:45%}}.popup .content{background:white;padding:20px 20px 20px 220px;min-height:240px;width:100%}.popup .content:before{content:'';position:absolute;background:url('/landingpageimg/044/girl-20161219.png');top:0;left:0;width:400px;height:480px;background-position:400px 0;-webkit-transform:scale(.5);-moz-transform:scale(.5);-o-transform:scale(.5);-ms-transform:scale(.5);transform:scale(.5);-webkit-transform-origin:left top 0;-moz-transform-origin:left top 0;-o-transform-origin:left top 0;-ms-transform-origin:left top 0;transform-origin:left top 0}@media (max-width:619px){.popup .content{padding:20px !important}.popup .content:before{display:none !important}}.popup .content .popup-title{font-size:160%;font-weight:bold;margin-bottom:15px;padding:5px 20px}.popup .content .subcategory-name{font-size:130%;font-weight:bold}@media (max-width:767px){.popup .content .subcategory-name{padding-bottom:15px}}.popup .content .course-link{display:block;margin-bottom:8px}@media (max-width:767px){.popup .content .course-link{margin-bottom:25px;font-size:120%}}@media (max-width:900px){.ui-dialog{width:auto !important}}.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-title{display:none}.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close{position:absolute;top:10px;right:10px;z-index:99;font-size:0;border:1px solid gray;width:24px;height:22px;background:url("/img/close_frame_b.png") no-repeat 50% 50%;cursor:pointer}.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close:hover{background-color:#feea7c}.redir-button{display:inline-block;position:relative;text-decoration:none;font-weight:bold;font-size:160%;margin:30px auto;padding:10px 75px 10px 50px;color:white;background-color:#f52020;border:2px solid white;border-radius:15px;cursor:pointer;-webkit-box-shadow:0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);-moz-box-shadow:0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);box-shadow:0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)}.redir-button:before,.redir-button:after{content:'';position:absolute;top:calc(50% - 16px);display:inline-block;background:url('/landingpageimg/044/full-sprite-20161219.png') no-repeat;overflow:hidden;text-indent:-9999px;text-align:left;background-position:-527px -216px;width:23px;height:32px}.redir-button:before{right:50px}.redir-button:after{right:40px}.redir-button:hover{background-color:#e20a0a}@media (max-width:767px){.redir-button{margin:10px auto}}#scroll-top{position:fixed;bottom:20px;right:20px;width:70px;height:70px;z-index:2}@media (max-width:1099px){#scroll-top{border-radius:100%;background:#fee249}}#scroll-top:before{content:'';display:block;display:inline-block;background:url('/landingpageimg/044/full-sprite-20161219.png') no-repeat;overflow:hidden;text-indent:-9999px;text-align:left;background-position:-413px -599px;width:70px;height:70px}#scroll-top:hover:before{-webkit-transition:all .5s ease;-moz-transition:all .5s ease;-o-transition:all .5s ease;transition:all .5s ease}.animated{-webkit-animation-duration:1s;animation-duration:1s;-webkit-animation-fill-mode:both;animation-fill-mode:both}.flipInY{-webkit-backface-visibility:visible !important;backface-visibility:visible !important;-webkit-animation-name:flipInY;animation-name:flipInY}@keyframes flipInY{from{-webkit-transform:perspective(400px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 90deg);transform:perspective(400px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 90deg);-webkit-animation-timing-function:ease-in;animation-timing-function:ease-in;opacity:0}40%{-webkit-transform:perspective(400px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg);transform:perspective(400px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg);-webkit-animation-timing-function:ease-in;animation-timing-function:ease-in}60%{-webkit-transform:perspective(400px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 10deg);transform:perspective(400px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 10deg);opacity:1}80%{-webkit-transform:perspective(400px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -5deg);transform:perspective(400px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -5deg)}to{-webkit-transform:perspective(400px);transform:perspective(400px)}}.flipInY{-webkit-backface-visibility:visible !important;backface-visibility:visible !important;-webkit-animation-name:flipInY;animation-name:flipInY}
```

```html
<div class="table bonus">
                <div class="market-sbs">Первая строка<br>Вторая строка</div>
                <span class="market-propose">+</span>
                <span class="market-full"><br>Первая строка<br>Вторая строка</span>
            </div>
```

Но если поставить `<br>` перед первой строкой все Ок.
С чем связано?

Comment: Может цсску таки несжатую приведете?

Comment: Пропадает она из-за правила, .congretulation, .courses-design, .courses-english, .courses-german, .courses-italian, .courses-manicure, .courses-other, .courses-poland, .courses-psyhology, .courses-sew, .market-sbs, .market-full, .certificate-1, .logo-white, .IgorNevzorov, .ElenaMatvienko, .AlinaPetrakova, .certificate-2, .scroll-top-arrow, .prize, .list-item-hand-black, .home, .phone, .white-button-arrow, .select-button, .black-button-arrow, .condition-mark {text-indent: 9999px;} Сильно помогло?

Comment: Оригинал в LESS файле, если его добавлять, то привышается предел в 30к символов, а LESS сразу в минку генерится. Через инспектор думаю вы увидите только используемые классы. Или если кто знает как добавить LESS?

Comment: Вот исчезает она из за того что отступ первой строки намеренно задан таким чтобы первая строка уезжала за границы экрана. Почему так сделано, остается только гадать.

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка Вы чертовски правы, вовсе забыл что названия классов одинаковы. Добавте в ответы прийму. Это происходит из за того что на этот же класс повешена часть спрайта.

Comment: ок, вынес в ответ если это действительно помогло)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Первая строка исчезает, потому что на нее действует примерно такое правило:

```
.market-sbs {text-indent: 9999px;}
```

То есть отступ первой строки для этого дива намеренно задан таким чтобы уезжать далеко за границы экрана.

Comment: На самом деле идет две таких таблицы одна за одной польностью одинаковы, разный только родительский класс (у первой таблицы нету `.bonus`), и в ней вместо контента лежат спрайты, а что бы они были одинаковой ширины я классы и оставил, фон убрал `background: null;` а про `text-indent` забыл.

Comment: @Makarenko_I_V, бывает, типичный вечерний тупняк)